# consistency of two multiple hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, consistency

For a multiple hypothesis test $H_{10}, H_{20},...,H_{n0}$ (e.g. tests of difference of gene expressions; assume to be independent to simplify the question), there are two independent test statistics $T_a=\{T_{a1}, T_{a2}, ..., T_{an}\}$, $T_b=\{T_{b1}, T_{b2}, ..., T_{bn}\}$ (e.g. obtained from two labs), where $T_a$ is independent of $T_b$. The resulted p-values are $p_a=\{p_{a1}, p_{a2}, ..., p_{an}\}$, $p_b=\{p_{b1}, p_{b2}, ..., p_{bn}\}$. Is there any way to adjudge or quantify the consistency of the two test results, or how the two tests replicate each other? Either statistically or non-statistically.

Comment: consistency (to a lesser extent the same is true for replication) is a widely, maybe overused, word in science. what do you precisely mean by consistency?

Comment: Yes, my question is how to find a way define and quantify the consistency

Comment: my question was: what do you mean by consistency?